# How can I pause longer on a certain category?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the slideshow to pause on the first category? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){      

            var images = [
            { 
                 id:0,
                 images: ['media/image0.jpg'],
                    dom: null
             },
                { 
                    id:1,
                images: ['media/image1.jpg'],
                    dom: null

                },
                { 
                    id:2,
                 images: ['media/image2.jpg'],
                    dom: null

                },
                { 
                    id:3,
                     images: ['media/image3.jpg'],
                    dom: null

                },
                { 
                    id:4,
                                    images: ['media/image4.jpg'],
                    dom: null
                },
                { 
                    id:5,
                                       images: ['media/image5.jpg'],
                    dom: null
                },
                { 
                    id:6,
                                        images: ['media/image6.jpg'],
                    dom: null
                }
            ];

            function preloadImages(images, func) {        
                var i = 0;
                var cache = [];
                var loaded = 0;
                var num = images.length;

                for ( ; i < num; i++ ) (function(i) {

                    var new_image = $('<img/>').attr('src', images[i]).load(function(){
                        loaded++;

                        if(loaded == num)
                        {                                                
                            func();                   
                        }
                    });                     
                    cache.push(new_image);
                })(i);

                return true;
            };

            for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++) {   
                preloadImages(images[i].images, function () {});
            }


            var category = 0; // the current tab group to display
            var index = 0; // the current image in the tab group to display
            var slider = $("#slider-container");
            var timer = null;
            var speed = 1000;

            initCategories = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
                    images[i].dom = $("<ul/>").addClass("holder");
                    for (var j = 0; j < images[i].images.length; ++j) {
                        images[i].dom.append($("<li/>").addClass("slide").css("background", "url(" + images[i].images[j] + ") no-repeat"));
                    }
                }
            }

            switchCategory = function(newCategory) {
                //if (newCategory != category) {
                    category = newCategory;
                    $(".slideCat").removeClass("active");
                    $(".slideCat[rel='" + category + "']").addClass("active");
                    slider.empty().append(images[category].dom);
                //}
                index = 0;
                $(".holder", slider).css("margin-left", 0);
            }

            switchSlide = function(newSlide, animate) {
                //if (newSlide != index) {
                    index = newSlide;
                    var newMargin = $(".slide:first", slider).width() * -index;
                    if (animate) {
                        $(".holder", slider).animate({"margin-left": newMargin + "px"}, speed, null, null);
                    } else {
                        $(".holder", slider).css("margin-left", newMargin + "px");
                    }
                //}
            }

            doTransition = function() {
                ++index;
                if (index >= images[category].images.length) {
                    ++category;
                    if (category >= images.length) {
                        category = 0;
                    }
                    switchCategory(category);
                } else {
                    switchSlide(index, true);
                }
            }

            $(".slideCat").click(function (e) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                switchCategory(this.rel);
                timer = setInterval(doTransition, 5000);
                return false;
            });

            $(".prev").click(function (e) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                --index;
                if (index < 0) {
                    --category;
                    if (category < 0) {
                        category = images.length - 1;
                    }
                    switchCategory(category);
                    switchSlide(images[category].images.length - 1);
                } else {
                    switchSlide(index);
                }
                timer = setInterval(doTransition, 5000);
                return false;
            });

            $(".next").click(function (e) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                ++index;
                if (index >= images[category].images.length) {
                    ++category;
                    if (category >= images.length) {
                        category = 0;
                    }
                    switchCategory(category);
                } else {
                    switchSlide(index, false);
                }
                timer = setInterval(doTransition, 15000);
                return false;
            });

            // this doesn't work! hover gets triggered like this, but we don't know which <li/> we're over.
            // if we use e.g. $(".holder", slider) or $("li", slider), the event doesn't get triggered :(
            $(slider).hover(function () {
                console.log("hover");
                clearInterval(timer);
                $(this).find(".caption").stop().fadeTo(500, 0.8);
            }, function() {
                $(this).find(".caption").stop().fadeTo(500, 0);
                timer = setInterval(doTransition, 15000);
            });

            // load the categories
            initCategories();
            switchCategory(0);
            switchSlide(0, false);
            timer = setInterval(doTransition, 15000);
       });
```

Comment: Are you sure you've posted enough code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your comments in the code that you're also struggling with the `.hover()` event handler. To get this working, try changing the `slider` variable from the jQuery object `$('#slider-container')` to the string `'#slider-container'`, and change your calls to the variable from `slider` to `$(slider)` accordingly. Finally, for the `.hover()` event, change `$(slider).hover` to `$(slider+' li').hover`. This will attach the `hover` event handler to each child list-item of `#slider-container`.

EDIT: here's how to achieve the desired transition effect:

First, in this block of code:

```
// load the categories
initCategories();
switchCategory(0);
switchSlide(0, false);
timer = setInterval(doTransition, 15000);
```

change `timer = setInterval(doTransition, 15000);` to:

```
timer = setTimeout(doTransition, 20000);
```

This will put a 20-second delay, after the very first image is loaded, before replacing it with the second image.

Next, change all other instances of `setInterval` to `setTimeout` and `clearInterval` to `clearTimeout`. This will give us more control over the length of each transition (`setInterval` starts an infinite action-delay loop, while `setTimeout` happens only once.)

Finally, in your `doTransition()` function, after `switchCategory(category);`, enter either:

```
timer = setTimeout(doTransition, 20000);
```

...if you want the first image in EVERY category to have a 20 second delay, or:

```
if (category == 0) 
{
    timer = setTimeout(doTransition, 20000);
}
else
{
    timer = setTimeout(doTransition, 15000);
}
```

to apply the 20 second delay to ONLY the very first image in your slideshow.

Last, but not least, after `switchSlide(index, true);`, enter:

```
timer = setTimeout(doTransition, 15000);
```

...to apply the standard 15 second delay to the remaining inter-slide transitions. That should be everything you need!

Comment: ha thanks Aaron. I'm not using the hover anymore though. it was for captions. can you help me pause the first category though?

Comment: Are you not seeing pauses between ANY of your transitions? Or are you just trying to make the first pause take longer?

Comment: Yes, all the pauses are working fine. I have them switching every 10 seconds. I would just like the first image to not switch until maybe 20 seconds. I didn't write this, but I'm guessing something like `if(category[i] = 0) { pause for 20 sec}` That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think yuriy was frustrated by the amount of code in your original post. Yeah, getting downvoted sucks, but take it in stride and you'll recoup your losses in no time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5864/discussion-between-tcc-and-aaron)